# Шестиугольную рамка

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на картину, появлялась данная шестиугольная голубая рамка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на картинке у вас не правильный шестиугольник, а с изогнутыми гранями. как вариант, подставлять при наведении картинку с рамкой с нужным цветом или окрашивать её

Comment: Есть сайт [http://csshexagon.com](http://csshexagon.com/) . Все нарисует за тебя)

Answer (score 4):

Вариантов существует предостаточно. Итак :

1. Создайте картинку с рамкой и картинку без. При наведении замените картинку (*Плюсы - простой код. Минусы — не удобно, когда множество картинок*).
2. Реализация через `transform: scale(N)`.(*Плюсы — сработает для всего. Минусы — при увеличении видна кривизна и неправильность формы*). Фиддлы : [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/aoghkqhc/7/) и [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/EZqCz/).
3. Реализация обычной рамки. Несомненно, самый простой, однотипный, и без заморочек способ) (*Плюсы — быстрая, простая реализация. Минусы — Опять же, при увеличении будут некоторое время видны составляющие элементы*). [Фиддл здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/bj9Rb/1/).
4. SVG. Очень хороший способ, но, возможно, в данной ситуации излишне будет его здесь использовать.(*Плюсы - кроссбраузерность, любые задачи, при зуме будет оставаться тем же изображением. Минусы - нету*). Документация [здесь(Мозилла)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG), [здесь(Хабрахабр)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/157087/) и [вот здесь (Тут английский, за надобностью можно перевести).](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) [Пример для SVG(CodePen)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqXJEx).

```css
body {
  font-family: "PT Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.hex {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.hex:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 5;
}

.hex {
  transition: transform, fill-opacity, stroke-width;
  -webkit-transition: transform, fill-opacity, stroke-width;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Fill</h1>

<svg id="image-fill" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="300" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <pattern id="image-bg" x="0" y="0" height="300" width="300" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/306/306"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <polygon class="hex" points="300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20" fill="url('#image-bg')"/>
</svg>
```

5. Наконец 5-ый, и последний способ. `Clip-Path`. Также является одним из свойств `SVG`, но, всё-таки, является отдельным компонентом этой картины.(*Огромный плюс — вы можете не напрягаясь "вырезать" из картинки любую форму. Минус — достаточно кропотливая работа, не все браузеры поддерживают это свойство.*). [Документация тут (На английском)](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/), примеры [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/maskirovanie-v-css), и Фиддл [вот тут](https://jsfiddle.net/sr3w7hsv/).

---

***И похожий вопрос : [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418486/hexagon-shape-with-a-border-outline)***.

Comment: А почему `SVG` не рекомендуете, можете подробнее?

Comment: @Arthur, я, скорее, не совсем корректно выразился: имел в виду, что в данной ситуации я бы использовал `Clip-Path` вместо чистого `SVG`, так как последний мне кажется слишком громоздким. Сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: `SVG` будет уместным, так как он намного кроссбраузернее, чем свойство `clip-path`.

Comment: Вы правы, об этом не знал. Сейчас еще раз поменяю.

Comment: Лови плюс:) Если интересует SVG — можешь присоединяться сюда https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку :) Да и за плюс тоже

Answer (score 1):

На англ. шестиугольник будет `hexagon`. Если искать по этому названию, то можно получить нечто вот такое:

```css
body {
  background: #fff
}
.rhex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 10em; height: 17.32em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  opacity: .25;
  background: orange;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rhex:before, .rhex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.rhex:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.rhex:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.rhex:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='rhex'></div>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Но у псевдоэлементов размеры надо 100%, а не inherit (иначе, не выйдет его резиновым сделать). А ещё, границу из такого не очень-то получится получить.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать `border-image`.

Шестиугольный фон должен занимать всю область блока вместе с границами, а через `border-image` поверх накладывается шестиугольная рамка (остальная часть прозрачна).

Для IE придётся дополнительно прописать `border-color: transparent`.